# How to animate multiple buttons in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, button, windows-phone-8

I am developing a  Windows phone game appsand I need to animate multiple buttons on certain event say Page_loaded. What i can achieve is that

```
<Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="scaButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" >
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" 
                     From="-1" To="1"                                                           
                     BeginTime="0:0:0"
                     Duration="0:0:0.5"
                     AutoReverse="False" />
        </Storyboard>
```

And in the XAML in a single button

```
<Button Height="100" Width="200" Margin="10,495,270,103" Content="{Binding Path=ListOfValues[0]}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Click="Button_Click">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
               <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaButton" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX="50" CenterY="25" />
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>
```

But the problem is how do I define it for Multiple buttons. I want all the buttons will flipAnimation at the sametime. But how do I achieve it?

please help.
In windows Phone `<Style.Triggers>` is also not present.

Comment: You have to create storyborad for each of your button. Because it is not possible to set multiple targets to one storyborad.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar that's the idea I implemented that but isn't there a single solution to animate all the buttons at once as the animation effects is same for all the buttons? And any idea how do I achieve Flip animation for buttons?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by setting the TargetName inside the DoubleAnimation

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FlipButtonStory">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scaButton1"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" 
                 From="-1" To="1"                                                           
                 BeginTime="0:0:0"
                 Duration="0:0:0.5"
                 AutoReverse="False" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scaButton2"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" 
                 From="-1" To="1"                                                           
                 BeginTime="0:0:0"
                 Duration="0:0:0.5"
                 AutoReverse="False" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scaButton3"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" 
                 From="-1" To="1"                                                           
                 BeginTime="0:0:0"
                 Duration="0:0:0.5"
                 AutoReverse="False" />
    </Storyboard>
<Grid.Resouces>
```

You can begin the story by calling the [BeginStoryboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.beginstoryboard.aspx) method.

```
FlipButtonStory.BeginStoryboard();
```

Comment: Thanks for the update but by this answer i come to know that there is not single solution that's applicable to all the buttons in the page. Anyways this works fine. Only thing I need to add is `<Button.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaButton4" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX="75" CenterY="50" />
                </Button.RenderTransform>`